# Pass data from a ViewModel to the other on iOS MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM so I'm having some problems implementing a simple app. Let say I have a screen `OrderViewController`:

```swift
class OrderViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel = OrderViewModel()
}

class OrderViewModel {
    var order = Order()
}
```

I have another screen `ProductsViewController`, which can be opened from `OrderViewController`:

```swift
class ProductsViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel = ProductsViewModel()
}

class ProductsViewModel {
    var order: Order?
}
```

Some logics inside `ProductsViewModel` depend on `order` model, so I must pass `order` from `OrderViewModel` to `ProductsViewModel`. How can I do that without breaking MVVM? If I just do this:

```swift
class OrderViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel = OrderViewModel()

    func showProductsViewController() {
        let vc = ProductsViewController()
        vc.viewModel.order = self.viewModel.order
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc)
    }
}
```

Is that wrong because I reference model (`order`) from a view (`OrderViewController`)?

Answer (score 2):

```
class ProductsViewModel {
    var order: Order?

    init(order : Order) {
        self.order = order
    }
}

class ProductViewController {
     var viewModel : Product?
     init(viewModel : Order) {
         self.viewModel = ProductsViewModel(order : viewModel)
     }
}
```

and call this

```
func showProductsViewController() {
    let vc = ProductsViewController(viewModel : order)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc)
}
```

Why?

This is because in MVVM every viewModel is bind to a single ViewController. `ProductViewModel` to `ProductViewController`, `OrderViewModel` to `OrderViewController`. ViewController shouldn't know, which data I have to pass to other ViewController.

All the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815549/ios-how-to-pass-a-model-from-view-model-to-view-model-using-mvvm/43820233#43820233)