# Best way to pass data while navigate to another VC with MVVM RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and MVVM , my old project used to pass data between VC via "prepare for segue" . Currently I'm successfully integrated RxSwift and MVVM to the project .

What is the best practice to pass data between VCs ?

A) Inside VC1 , -GoToAnotherVC(). 
  Simple create Model2 object , pass data

```
  Model.valueA = Model2.valueA.
```

then

```
   DestinationVC.model = Model2
```

B) Create Model2 within VC1 immediately , Use Rx Magic to bind Model1.value and Model2.value

C) Any better approach ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: How to pass a model from view model to view model using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815549/ios-how-to-pass-a-model-from-view-model-to-view-model-using-mvvm)

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather extensive topic, but I'll try to keep it short. For screen transitions you might want to check out the RxFlow framework: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxFlow which I've been using with a lot of success.

Second thing is you don't really want to pass data from one view model to the next one. Instead I would suggest to have some sort of factory pattern to create the view models and while creating them you pass in all the needed objects from the model layer via dependency injection. This way each view model will be able to retrieve whatever pieces of data it needs from the model layer without depending on other view models. Also, this makes writing proper unit tests a relative piece of cake.